# How to remove custom entity fields when we uninstall the module in Drupal 8?

Tags: drupal, entity, drupal-8

In my custom module, I have programmatically added three new fields to the User entity. Now when I uninstall the module, these new fields are not removed and when I install the module again, it gives me an error because the entity fields already exist. Any solution to this?